# "could have +past participle" and "couldn't have +past participle" meaning in Interrogative sentences

Tags: negation, interrogatives

I know that "could have +past participle" and "couldn't have +past participle" have different meanings when we use them in Declarative sentences, but I think when we use them in Interrogative sentences they have the same meaning. Am I right? Examples: Could you have been nicer at the party? couldn't have you been nicer at the party?

Comment: pp: present perfect

Comment: Examples: Could you have been nicer at the party? couldn't have you been  nicer at the party?

Comment: We do not use _more_ with adjectives which end in _-er_ or _-est._ See [**this link.**](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/es/gramatica/gramatica-britanica/comparison-adjectives-bigger-biggest-more-interesting)

Comment: PP (note case!) == past participle. Can you add example sentences to illustrate your question? Do you mean "could +present perfect" e.g. "could _have driven"?_

Comment: @Cardinal Your edit incorporated my _mistaken_ edit! The OP intended _present perfect,_ and I misunderstood it. Perhaps we can persuade him to add some examples...

Comment: "could have +present perfect" would render as, for instance, _"could have have driven,"_ and I know that is not your intention. I think you mean **could +present perfect.** If so, please use the [edit] link to change your question (and add examples.)

Comment: pp should be past participle not present perfect. see suggested edit description.  pp has to be the most unhelpful abbreviation in ELT... past perfect, present perfect, past participle... nightmare

Comment: @P.E.Dant I completely agree with your edit suggestion and I have never seen anything like "could have have driven" before. I think OP meant to mention the underlying perfect aspect of the "could+have+Past Participle". Under any circumstances, the tags must be improved!

Comment: @Cardinal Note OP's first comment. He must have intended _could +present perfect._ If he won't clarify, I'll vote to close. A shame, because this could be an interesting question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*couldn't have* in the interogative implies that I think you could have.

*could have* does not indicate my opinion.

*"Couldn't he arrive earlier?"*  means I think you **could** arrive earlier next time, and I am asking you if I am correct.

*"Could he arrive earlier?"* means I do not necessarily have an opinion on whether he will be able to arrive earlier.

This is true for in general for negative interrogatives.  They imply my opinion, and are often used to **disagree** with someone.

*"Shouldn't I talk to John?"*  Means I think I **should** talk to John, but I want your opinion.

*"If I go to London, should I visit Buckingham Palace?"* is neutral.  I am not expressing my opinion.

Comment: Dear some-guy:what about " could you have arrived earlier?"

Comment: @MehrdadMoshaver It is more likely that you would say "couldn't you have arrived earlier?", which means "I think you could have arrived earlier, what do you think?".   Could you have arrived earlier means literally "is it possible that you were able to arrive earlier?".